# jQuery send more then one formdata

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, blueimp

Currently my code is

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    // The example input, doesn't have to be part of the upload form:
    var adultinput = $('#adult');
    data.formData = {adult: adultinput.val()};
    if (!data.formData.adult) {
       input.focus();
       return false;
     }
});
```

Which works just fine to send a post data with adult value from the html code

However there's another input form called thumbsize which i want to send as well,

I tried

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
     // The example input, doesn't have to be part of the upload form:
    var adultinput = $('#adult');
    var thumbsize = $('#thumbsize');
    data.formData = {adult: adultinput.val()};
    data.formData = {thumbsize: thumbsize.val()};
    if (!data.formData.adult) {
        input.focus();
        return false;
     }
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work, is there anyway i can go about sending another parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
data.formData = {adult: adultinput.val()};
data.formData = {thumbsize: thumbsize.val()};
```

With the second line you’re *overwriting* what you assigned in the first one.

Put both values into *one* object:

```
data.formData = {adult: adultinput.val(), thumbsize: thumbsize.val()};
```